# How to check if the custom DialogFragment is displayed?

Tags: android, notifications, dialogfragment

1) In my application, the user may receive **a lot of notifications** from FCM
2) If the user has an application open, he needs **to display the custom DialogFragment**
3) If the DialogFragment is already displayed, then the next time the notification arrives, it is necessary **to prohibit the repeated display of this DialogFragment**
4) My dialogue code:

```
public final class NotificationEventDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnKeyListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private Activity mCurrentActivity;
    private NotificationEventDialogListener mNotificationEventDialogListener;

    public interface NotificationEventDialogListener {
        void showEvent();
    }

    public NotificationEventDialog() {
    }

    public static NotificationEventDialog newInstance() {
        NotificationEventDialog notificationEventDialog = new NotificationEventDialog();
        notificationEventDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return notificationEventDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCurrentActivity = (Activity)context;
        try {
            mNotificationEventDialogListener = (NotificationEventDialogListener) mCurrentActivity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(mCurrentActivity.toString() + " must implemented NotificationEventDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCurrentActivity);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_notification_event, null);

        Button btnNotificationEventYes = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_event_dialog_yes);
        btnNotificationEventYes.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btnNotificationEventNo = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_event_dialog_no);
        btnNotificationEventNo.setOnClickListener(this);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCurrentActivity);
        builder.setView(view);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().setOnKeyListener(this);
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCurrentActivity = null;
        mNotificationEventDialogListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.notification_event_dialog_yes:
                dismiss();
                mNotificationEventDialogListener.showEvent();
                break;
            case R.id.notification_event_dialog_no:
                dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            dismiss();
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

5) Each time I receive a notification from FCM, I create a dialog box:

```
DialogFragment notificationEventDialog = NotificationEventDialog.newInstance();  
notificationEventDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

6) **How to check if DialogFragment is already displayed?** Every time I create a new object of this window and I cannot make it as Singleton, because This leads to a memory leak.

[Found an answer in which](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36382705/4512868) a person suggests using Weak links to solve this problem:

> Also you can store a weak link to the shown dialog in that singletone
>   class. Using such method, you can detect is your dialog currently
>   shown or not.

There was also such an answer:

> I suggest to save link to the dialog in single instance class. In that
>   instance create method ensureShowDialog(Context context). That method
>   would check is current shown dialog or not. If yes, you can show the
>   dialog. In another casr you can pass new data you to the dialog.

But, honestly, **I can’t quite understand how to use these tips in practice**. Please can help with this realization or suggest another way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if dialog fragment is showing by calling [isAdded ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#isAdded()) inside DialogFragment or by

```
DialogFragment notificationEventDialog = NotificationEventDialog.newInstance();
notificationEventDialog.isAdded()
```

from activity

It will return true if fragment is added to an Activity, in case of dialog fragment - is shown.

You can store last shown dialog fragment date via putting `System.currentTimeMillis()` in SharedPreferences

I think you'v got the idea.

Comment: I doubt your idea with `isAdded` method, because `NotificationEventDialog.newInstance()` create NEW object and correspondingly - new DialogFragment. And every time i will receive that my DialogFragment is added.

Comment: So, please, provide the clarification.
You need display DialogFragment this message from FCM? And you need to know, whether dialog fragment already displayed that concrete message or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    val ft: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
    val prev: Fragment? = fragmentManager!!.findFragmentByTag("typeDialog")

    if (prev == null) {
        val fm = fragmentManager
        val courseTypeListDialogFragment =
            CourseTypeListDialogFragment()
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.isCancelable = false
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.setStyle(
            DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,
            0
        )
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1)
        if (fm != null) {
            courseTypeListDialogFragment.show(ft, "typeDialog")
        }
    }
```